# Viber not supported in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dpkg, deb, viber

I have downloaded Viber and installed it via terminal to my Ubuntu 14.04 OS. For the installation I have used `dpkg -i` to install and `apt-get install -f` to install the dependencies:

```
wget -O viber.deb http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb  
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Although Viber is installed, it cannot be launched. Executing it via the terminal, I get the output bellow:

```
$ /opt/viber/Viber
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./Viber)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./Viber)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Location.so.5)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libicui18n.so.52)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libicuuc.so.52)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5)
./Viber: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
```

I guess it has something to do with having an older version of some dependencies than required. The OS is up to date though. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install libstdc++6` solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to install previous version - 4.2.2.6. I found it on the [archive site](https://viber-for-linux.ru.uptodown.com/ubuntu).
Its MD5 is `4dec3ade37a3738c6f084858a4554861`, so it [does not modified](http://ftp.vim.org/ftp/os/Linux/distr/salix/sbo/14.1/network/viber/viber.info).

Then install it as you did before:

```
sudo dpkg -i viber-for-linux-4-2-2-6-en-ubu.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

On my 14.04 LTS it launches normally.

**Update:** I got latest Viber 7.0.0.1035 working on my 14.04 LTS after manual downloading of libstdc++ from Xenial (16.04 LTS) to `/opt/viber/lib` directory:

```
wget -O viber.deb http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb
dpkg -x libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb /tmp/stdc
sudo cp /tmp/stdc/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6* /opt/viber/lib

sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5 # prevent errors about xcb
```

Comment: I did this all. Viber still doesn't open but this time there are no errors in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-4.9
sudo apt install libstdc++6
```

I think the above programs are not installed properly.

Comment: How does this solve the OP's original question?  (It actually sounds to me like this is a case of them using too old an OS for the software they're trying to install, not a case of things not being installed properly)

Comment: This worked fine for me.